# iOS Repeated calling of CGContext.save/restoreGState (aka CGContextSave/RestoreGState) resulting in jaggies

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uigraphicscontext

After numerous experiments I found out that drawing an image in a context after repeatedly calling `saveGState()` and `restoreGState` results in jaggies.

This is something I observed in iOS 8, 9, and 10. So I don't think it's tied to any one iOS version.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

for i in 0 ... count {
    ctx?.saveGState()

    // Some clipping done
    image.draw(in: self.bounds)

    values.append(animImage)
    ctx?.restoreGState()
}

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

The code above is a simplified version of what I did.
I actually needed to loop `count` number of times to clip various parts of the `image`, and found jaggies.

Calling 2 or 3 times seems to be okay--maybe. I didn't do a side-by-side comparison--but around 10 times, it definitely happens.

Below are the images:

[image: Jaggies]
[image: No Jaggies]

I was able to solve the problem by moving `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` into the loop, but am not too sure about the performance.

Is the quality drop an expected issue or is this a subtle bug?
Also, what's the performance impact of beginning a new context for each iteration, if any, compared to calling `save/restoreGState()`?

(I'm only asking because I might not have enough time to test, but it doesn't matter too much)

Comment: Any reason why you are saving and restoring the state so much? Looks to me like it is not necessary. But looks like a subtle bug. Have you tested across multiple OS versions?

Comment: I just added about the version info. Happens in iOS 8, 9, and 10. As I mentioned in the post, I have to clip various parts of the context.

Comment: Have you tried setting `CGContextSetShouldAntialias` (the Swift 3 equivalent) after restoring?

Comment: I tried it right after calling `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`. Should it matter whether I call it after restoring though?

Comment: Well, to me it seems like there is a bug that happens with antialiasing after many restores. So perhaps setting it after restoring will offset the problem.

Comment: I think you need to remove the previous graphic before drawing again. It looks like you a adding new layers over the old layers, this makes the anti-aliasing look sharp and jagged, because the opacity of the edge pixels is built up each time.

Comment: This may be part of what `UIGraphicsBeginContextWithOptions` is doing for you.

Comment: It's no surprise `UIGraphicsBeginContextWithOptions` is working because I'm basically getting a clean slate each time. And @Sarcoma you're right! Adding `ctx?.clear(self.bounds)`worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the previous graphic before drawing again. It looks like you are adding new layers over the old layers, this makes the anti-aliasing look sharp and jagged because the opacity of the edge pixels is built up each time.

This is what UIGraphicsBeginContextWithOptions is doing for you, as you have stated in the comments it gives you a clean slate each time.

So, as you have discovered adding `ctx?.clear(self.bounds)` fixes the issue.